# Why is $x^3-x^2+x$ injective?

Tags: functions, cubics

The function $$ f(x) = x^3-x^2+x$$ is injective (as seen on the graph), but by doing f(a) = f(b) I can't get to the point where a = b.

[image]

Can this be indicated in an analytical way (without graph) ?

Comment: The derivative $$3x^2-x+1$$ is positive on the whole real line (I hope you are able to check it). This implies that the function is monotone, and, in particular, injective.

Comment: do you think we can get something out of $x^3-x^2+x-a$ and using cardano?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the easiest way to see that this is injective is via calculus: if for some $a\not=b$ we had $f(a)=f(b)$, there would have to be some $c$ with $f'(c)=0$. But $f'(x)=3x^2-2x+1$, which has no (real) solutions.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the answer !

Comment: Is that from Rolle's theorem ?

Answer (score 6):

Without calculus, you can inspect the expression $f(a)-f(b)=0$ using
$$
\begin{align}
f(a)-f(b)&=(a^3-a^2+a)-(b^3-b^2+b)\\
&=(a-b)\left((a^2+ab+b^2)-(a+b)+1 \right)\\
&=\textstyle(a-b)\left[ \left(a+\frac{b-1}2\right)^2+\frac34\left( b-\frac13\right)^2+\frac23\right],
\end{align}
$$
and note that the second term on the right can never be zero.

Answer (score 5):

We do it the "hard" way, using algebra only.

Let us calculate $f(a)-f(b)$. This is
$$(a^3-b^3)-(a^2-b^2)+(a-b).$$
Factor out $a-b$ out of each term. We get
$$(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2-a-b+1).$$
We want to show that $a^2+ab+b^2-a-b+1$ is never $0$. It is easy to verify that it cannot be $0$ if $a=0$. So assume that $a\ne 0$. Then we can think of our expression as a quadratic in $a$.

The disciminant is $(b-1)^2-4(b^2-b+1)$, which simplifies to 
$$-3b^2+2b-3.$$
It is easy to verify that this is never $0$, and therefore always negative.

Comment: Almost beat me to that sir :-)

Comment: Thank you for noticing! PS I retract my "bragging" of sorts.. Oh, well

Answer (score 2):

Well, you should not give up hope on that $f(a)=f(b)$ approach :-):

$$f(a)=f(b)\\a^3-a^2+a=b^3-b^2+b\\a^3-b^3-(a^2-b^2)+(a-b)=0\\(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2-a-b+1)=0$$
Which means that either $a=b$ or $a^2+ab+b^2-a-b+1=0$
Considering this as a quadratic with respect to a, we calculate it's discriminant as $$\Delta=(b-1)^2-4(b^2-b+1)=\\-3b^2+2b-3$$Which can be showed to be $<0$. 

Thus we must have $a=b$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f(a)=f(b)$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.  Then, since $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable, by Rolle's Theorem there must be some point $c \in (a,b)$ with $f'(c)=0$.  But one can check directly that the equation $f'(x)=0$ has no real solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(a) = f(b)$, then $f(a)-f(b) = 0 \iff a^3-a^2+a -b^3+b^2-b = 0 \iff a-b = a^2(1-a) -b^2(1+b)$

But this means
$2(a-b) = a^2(1-a) -b^2(1+b) + a - b = (f(a)-f(b)) = 0$, from which $a = b$ follows.

Comment: In the second line it must be
\begin{align*}
a-b&=a^2-a^3-b^2+b^3\\
&=a^2(1-a)-b^2(1-b)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without derivatives. For $a>0$ we have$$\begin{align}f(x+a)-f(x)&=(x+a)^3-(x+a)^2+(x+a)-(x^3-x^2+x)\\&=3ax^2+3a^2x+a^3-2ax-a^2+a\\&=a(3(x+\tfrac a2-\tfrac13)^2+\tfrac{a^2}4+\tfrac23)\\&>0\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

It's monotonically increasing because $f'(x)=3x^2-2x+1=3(x-\frac{1}{3})^2+\frac{2}{3}>0$ so it has to be injective.